# How to get the updated/modified HttpServletRequest object from AOP @Before advice to Spring controller method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I used Spring AOP @Before advice in Spring boot application, and it should execute before hitting any api's.
My task/requirement :- If in the request header application-name is not passed then we should modify the header and add to 'unknown' value to the application-name for every API.
I am modifying the header in the AOP @before advice using HttpServletWrapper class as shown below.

**Problem is - the AOP should return updated HttpServletrequest to a controller method but it's not working, not returning the updated one in controller**.

Controller:-

```
@GetMapping
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public ResponseEntity<String> getEmployee(HttpServletRequest request) {
    
    System.out.println("Header, application-name"+request.getHeader("application-name"));
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Spring AOP code,

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AOPExample {

   @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping) ||"
        + "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping)")
   public void controllerRequestMapping() {}

   @Before("controllerRequestMapping()")
   public HttpServletRequest advice(JoinPoint jp) {
    
       HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest();
       String header = request.getHeader("application-name");
       if (header == null) {
            HttpServletRequestWrapperClass wrappedRequest = new HttpServletRequestWrapperClass(request);
            wrappedRequest.putHeader("application-name", "Unknown");
            request = wrappedRequest;
       } else {
           //validate application name
          //400 - throw bad request exception
       }
       System.out.println("After setting---"+request.getHeader("application-name"));
       return request;
     }
  }
```

Comment: why voted to -1 ? any reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue,

Instead of using @Before advice used @Around advice, Around advice should return the object using proceed method.

```
@Aspect   
@Component   
public class AOPExample {

   @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping) ||"
        + "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping)")
   public void controllerRequestMapping() {}

   @Around("controllerRequestMapping()")
   public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    
         HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest();
         String header = request.getHeader("application-name");
         System.out.println("Header in AOP"+header);
         if (header == null) {
              HttpServletRequestWrapperClass wrappedRequest = new HttpServletRequestWrapperClass(request);
              wrappedRequest.putHeader("application-name", "Unknown");
              request = wrappedRequest;
        } else {
            //validate application name
            //400 - throw bad request exception
            //throw new BadRequestException("Invalid application name");
        }
        System.out.println("After setting---"+request.getHeader("application-name"));
        return jp.proceed(new Object[] {request});
    }
}
```

Updated httpservlet request is getting in controller method. Thanks

Comment: That is a strange way to solve the problem. The `HttpServletRequest` is a parameter of the intercepted method. Why don't you just bind it to an advice parameter via `args()` pointcut designator? Using the `RequestContextHolder` is only necessary if the request is not a method parameter.

Comment: that's true. We can get the httpservletrequest in the proceedingjoint point arguments.

Comment: I did not mean joinpoint arguments like `jp.getArgs()[0]`, but more elegantly `... && args(request)` in the pointcut and then `ProceedingJoinPoint jp, HttpServletRequest request` as method arguments.